# In Backbone.js should I make static lists collections or just hardcode them into the UI?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a web app that I want to use Backbone.js for.  I have a list of common "items" which will not be edited by the user directly.  This will appear essentially as a menu to choose from on the left side of the screen.  When a user selects an item an "item instance" will be generated which they will customize.

I'm just wondering if this static list of items/templates should be handled by Backbone.js or if it should just be hardcoded.  The value in using a Backbone Collection/Models for the list is that each item will have another Backbone.Model property that will be instantiated when that item is selected from the list.  e.g. the HTMLImageChoice item, when selected, will result in an HTMLImage being instantiated.

I'm having trouble finding easy to follow examples of Backbone.js which are not very contrived.

Comment: Sounds to me like you do want to represent these menu items as a Backbone.collection. Can you give a bit more info on what's in the items, and what kind of customization you're doing to them, so we can mock it out?

Comment: It is sort of like a menu... it is a graphical/WYSIWYG website builder and the menu is a list of HTML elements.  When I select one from the menu its type is of importance, and that type will determine which Backbone.Model I instantiate and allow the user to customize.  The only reason it seemed reasonable to use a collection/model here is because I thought it might be more natural than hardcoding 30+ elements and then doing a string comparison to determine which model to instantiate.

Comment: To expand on that, I intended for each HTML element item that the user selects to be a model.  One property of each model would be the instance class to instantiate.  E.g. when the user selects a menu item I would do "new menuItem.get('classToInstantiate')" when creating an instance of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Collections in backbone are collections of models. It seems like you are just talking about a hardcoded array of strings, which are totally not a model. Maybe you would want to hang that array off of a model as a property, but that is as close to backbone as it will get.